# Переключатель boolean

Tags: java

Мой вопрос очень прост для программистов со стажем. Мне просто нужно, чтобы по клику менялось значение boolean с true на false и обратно.

```
boolean bol = obs.get(ii);
if(bol == true) { bol = false; }
if(bol == false) { bol = true; }
```

Пробовал так, но не работает. Думал, что проблема в том, что он сначала меняет на false, а потом видит, что там false, и обратно выводит true, но это не так. Выход, как был false, так и остался false.

Comment: Для присвоения значения используйте просто: bol = !bol

Answer (score 3):

Условные выражения не нужны, достаточно инвертировать текущее значение

```
boolean bol = !obs.get(ii);
```

Comment: Спасибо, чуть не так надо было, но в целом спасибо, я не знаю, как сам не догадался :)
`obs.set(ii, !obs.get(ii));`
Надо писать ответ самому себе, если проблема решена, или этого комментария хватит?

Comment: @asdqwertypro можете написать и отметить его решением, а можно и не писать.

Comment: asdqwertypro, но по большому счёту, не Вы ответили на собственный вопрос, а человек, который написал Вам ответ и не мешало бы поставить ему +1 )))